# How to disable Auto save in Xcode 4.3 after editing code?

Tags: xcode, autosave

I remember that there is an option to disable auto save in Xcode 4.2, but I can no longer find it in Xcode 4.3.
Is there another a way to disable auto save after editing code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been removed (unfortunately). See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3655734?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Solution (able to find in 10.8.2)  https://discussions.apple.com/message/20435985#20435985

1) Open the Settings app.

2) Open the General panel.

3) Check "Ask to keep changes when closing documents"